# When Alert dialog is opened,I need to access the background screen

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When Alert dialog is opened, I should have access to click functionality o a button in the background screen on which this alert dialog is appeared.
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you wish to send the click event or do you want the user to be able to "click" below the dialog, if so, should the dialog disappear or not?

Comment: set animation with fragment or Alertdialog....

Comment: I want the user to click below the dialog but dialog should not be closed

Answer (score 0):

Your alert dialog is a new fragment / activity. While you can see the background, you can not interact with it until you have handled the dialog. I would suggest that you use the built in positive / neutral / negative buttons to handle what ever it is you need.

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDialogs/article.html) is a good tutorial that might shine some light on your predicament.

Comment: My dialog is in activity.

Comment: As suggested by @hopeman you can'nt interact with activity if the dialog is opened, either way you have to use positive/negative buttons to perform action or before to call the dialog listener, call your background actions.